# Optimize repeating peace of jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, query-optimization

I'm newbie with js and jQuery and I've wrote a bit of code that I think can be optimized a bit. Here is what I have:

```
$(".team-member.personX").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".img-mask").attr("src", "images/img-mask-active.png");
    $(".member-info.personX").fadeIn();
});
$(".member-info.personX .close").click(function(){
    $(".team-member.personX .img-mask").attr("src", "images/img-mask.png");
    $(".member-info.personX").fadeOut();
});
```

In mainly I want to ask is there is a way how to Replace the **-- X --** with **1,2,3,4** without repeating the same code 4 time.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add another element with a new class that contains the elements, then it will work for all elements without numbers.

Comment: Please post your HTML.  There is a MUCH easier way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. The easiest way that I find to optimize my code is to use a function call.

Example:

```
function on(x){...}
$(person1).click(function{ on(1) }) and e.t.c.
```

It's not the best solution but it simple and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's about Javascript in general, not specifically jQuery.

A classic example of loops, actually. You could use a for-loop:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    //actions utilizing i taking values from 1 to 4
}
```

...and the fact that strings can be easily combined with numbers using `+`:

```
$(".member-info.person" + i).fadeIn(); //an example action
```

Comment: I tried this before- doesn't work because on click on person the effect is applied on all elements in the cycle. Any other ideas?

Comment: @NoSense, I don't see any reasons why it should work this way, could you share the exact code you've tried?